# Pass custom animations to Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation

I made an Angular npm library with Angular animations in a Component, but users want to customize them.

Let's say I have the following Angular 5+ component ([from Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/animations)):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  template: `
    template code here...
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./hero-list.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('heroState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
        transform: 'scale(1)'
      })),
      state('active',   style({
        backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
        transform: 'scale(1.1)'
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class HeroListBasicComponent {
   @Input() heroes: Hero[];
}
```

As the above example shows, `animations` are set inside the `@Component` decorator.

I would like to know if it's possible to pass custom `animations` array to the element in order to make it using different animations depending on the one passed to the element instance (regardless of how to achieve that):

- Custom service?
- @Input()?
- Global config script / variable / object?

Maybe it's not currently possible with actual Angular?

Comment: looking from documentation / the way how the animations are set up I would rather say it is impossible, especially to change it per component instance (still you can try having a reference to some shared property which can be a problem for AOT and anyway change it not per instance but per all instances of that component). Ask this on the angular github repo

Comment: @smnbbrv yes unfortunately I thought about that. Yes, it could also be for all instances as you say, it could be pretty cool anyway.

Comment: I dropped an issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not answer the question in a common way, but it can help you with this particular problem + the thing I am going to write is too big for a comment >> I will post it as an answer.

If the only thing we talk here is the animation for showing up the modal I would really switch to standard CSS animations.

They are simple to write (at least for my taste they are simpler than angular's) and simple to extend. You can give your users full freedom: they can configure the animations they want by just providing you a couple of CSS classes.

The steps to be happy:

1. As long as you control the popup from the service, you trigger its rendering, so when it gets created it should get the current state e.g. the class `initial-state` with `transform: scale(0)` and some class that holds the transition logic, let's say `transition-definition`.
2. Now you need to set up the timeout (with `setTimeout` or some of `rxjs` timeouts), that waits for 0ms. The only reason to do that is to let the browser render your modal scaled to 0. In the timeout's callback you remove the `initial-state` class and assign another class on your modal that gives you another state, let's say a class `target-state` with `transform: scale(1)`.

As long as you timed out the execution of the class, CSS engine recognises that element that has already been rendered was updated with a new property for `transform`. That's why it will start the transition by scaling from 0 to 1.

The only concern you should have is probably creating a timeout outside the Angular zone because it is only used for animations purposes and does not change the application state. This will save some electricity for the humanity.

Finally your users can provide you with any animations that look similar to

```
.initial-state {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.transition-definition {
  transition: transform .2s
}

.target-state {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

by just providing you a couple of CSS classes.

I guess even with 2 classes could be enough if you put transition logic into target-state (needs to be verified).

Comment: That's what I finally decided. I give with the library a `.scss` (and `.css`) file which does the job perfectly. Users can override some variables and add their own custom classes. But I hope Angular will make it possible in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done this like below

1. First create below animation file

**router.animations.ts**

```
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';

export function routerTransition() {
   return slideToTop();
}

export function slideToTop() {
 return trigger('routerTransition', [
    state('void', style({})),
    state('*', style({})),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)' }),
      animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
        style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)' }),
        animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateY(-100%)' }))
    ])
 ]);
}
```

2. In component

   `import { routerTransition } from './router.animations';
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-login',
     templateUrl: './login.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
     animations: [routerTransition()]
   })`

I hope it will helps you.

**Edit**: Forgot to add html code

In the parent node of component.html :

```
<div class="component-page" [@routerTransition]>
 <!-- Component layout -->
</div>
```